# How do I change an inconstant number to 0 a single time?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

In google sheets I have a table of names and numbers that can constantly change, I am trying to make it so when I type the name of a person (can be anywhere) then the numbers in that row will change back to 0, so far that is easy to do but the problem is after it will reset back to 0 it needs to allow numbers to change again, that's why it needs to only change the numbers once.

So far I made a somewhat working formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A2=VLOOKUP(A2,S$1:S,1, FALSE), -1, 0), 0)
```

Problem with that is it will subtract 1 from the number, so if the number is 3 then it will change the number to 2.

`=countif(A$1:A, E2)` - Counts how many times someone filled a form and adds up the number.
`=IFERROR(IF(A2=VLOOKUP(A2,S$1:S,1, FALSE), -1, 0), 0)` - Sees if a name matching the one it has in it's row was typed, and if it was then to subtract 1.

For example: Let's say Dave has the numbers `0 3 6` (each in their own cell but in the same row) and I put the name "Dave" anywhere in the sheet, what I want to happen is the numbers will be changed to `0 0 0` (it will do something like `-0, -3, -6`), but then keep counting after it reset the `0 3 6` to `0 0 0`.

Keep in mind the names are changing so having `"Human1"` or something like that in a formula won't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share a copy of your spreadsheet. You really haven't given us much to go on; there's a table, but we don't know the columns or the cells, or how many rows, but the "formula" has to trigger when the name is entered ("can be anywhere") on the Sheet. the formula etc, etc. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and then edit your question to give enough information to create a minimum workable example.

Comment: Alright! There you go: (I couldn't upload the images in the question because I dont have 10 points) ![This is where the names are typed in, it searches I column and if it is found then it subtracts given numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5RxE.jpg)
![This is what needs to be reset to `0 0 0`, this is where the numbers are being counted up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz7Kz.jpg)
![Column A-C is google form responses, then the table counts how many times each person filled the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCsyZ.jpg)

Comment: May I clarify? Please correct me if I am wrong. "https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5RxE.jpg" shows a training database in columns A to F. Columns A, B and C are generated by a Google Form (column A contains the user name). Columns D , E and F contain relevant numeric values. A user name can be entered in cell I2. When the user name is entered, the "system" should lookup this name in Column A, and set the Columns D, E, F values for that user to zero.

Comment: That is correct! But columns A, B and C are not generated by the google form, "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz7Kz.jpg" this table is. The image you showed has `0 0 0`'s by default, and will have `-X` (X = The inconstant number) as the the result for when a name matching the A column one is typed in the I column.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am sorry, I am totally confused about the role of each sheet, the relationships between the sheets, how and when each sheet is populated, and how your question relates to specific sheet(s). Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet and please ensure that the data is consistent between the sheets.  Would you please edit your question to explain the outcome(s) that you are trying to achieve - in words and sentences, please. The inclusion of formula (while necessary) does not help understand the desired outcome.

Comment: Would you please also ensure that your spreadsheet includes an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to all of this. Here is the copy of the spreadsheet: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CmP6Uu9UB3h2K6KWPmIPkNjmUyqILuUY_rReQOUPT9o/edit?usp=drivesdk" The "Project Automation" sheet is where the amount of events are counted, Columns A, B and C are google form responses. The "Names Lists" tab you can ignore as that's not a part of the problem, that is where names get added. "Manual Changes" tab is where it should say `-X` as an output (I said details about this before). "Final result 1 column" is where it needs to eventually have the 0 0 0, desired outcome is in row B

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using Apps Script would help you. To create a script in your sheet, go to `Tools > Script editor`. I'm not 100% sure if I understood your actual issue, but from your [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5RxE.jpg) I deduce that if you write a name that matches any value from the column A, it will replace the values from B, C and D with 0.

```
    function onEdit(e) {

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Final result 1 column");
      var col_A = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();

      var name_typed = e.value; //The value you just typed in the sheet

      for (var i = 0; i < col_A.length; i++){

        if (col_A[i] == name_typed){

          var range = sheet.getRange(i + 2, 2, 1, 3); //row found, first column, number of rows, number of columns
          var formulas = range.getFormulas(); //saves the formulas from B,C,D in the variable

          range.setValues([[0, 0, 0]]); //sets columns to zero
          range.setFormulas(formulas); //sets the formulas back to B,C,D

          break;
        }

      }
```

The script above gets the value you typed in any of the sheets, compares it with the column A of the "Final result 1 column" sheet and if it matches, replaces the values from B, C and D with 0. In the case that this columns have formulas, it saves them in a variable to write them right after setting the zeros.

If those cells don't have any formula, then comment the line `range.setFormulas...`.

**References**

- [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [getFormulas() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas())
- [setValues() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: I am getting this error: http://prntscr.com/psajr7
Also, fix me if I'm wrong but it seems like that script is resetting the values to `0 0 0` for as long as the name is typed? If so, it needs to only reset it once and then allow the numbers to keep counting.